# Google firebase - how to share database with other apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that, firebase there is a real time database and I have made use of it. But its based on authentication from the user first. What I would like to do is have the firebase realtime database share its content with other apps. Just like a `ContentProvider` in Android.

When I call :

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

This is going to get the firebaseDatabase only for my app. I want other apps to be able to use the real time database as well. How can they connect to it?

UPDATE:
Conceptually can a contentProvider solve this issue? since a contentProvider is just an abstraction and it does not care what the datasource is, instead of using sql as the source i could use firebase db. Then since the firebase db is wrapped inside a contentProvider i could then expose a URI for other apps to use and make the contentProvider public. I'll have to look more into this but should be possible since contentProvider is a wrapper for a data sources either network or local. The ContentProvider.query command would return a cursor though, not sure how to make a cursor out of the retrieved firebase data.

Comment: Other apps without adding the Firebase dependencies, you mean?

Comment: i dont mind if they have the firebase dependency. either way is fine. i just want a way to expose my firebase database to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 would be to implement a custom backend serving as an access point to the data via some authentication.

Option 2 would be to make all the data you want to share publicly available and get a reference to that database in the apps in question.

Option 1 would be safer and more reliable and configurable from a single place. Option 2 would be easier to implement.

Comment: regarding option 2. your saying there is a way in firebase dashboard to make the realtime database exposed to anyone ? if so i do not know how to do this. do i just change it in the rules ? i thought the firebase features are per app ?

Comment: You have to be able to add the services.json to the other apps in order to do this. If you want to share data to external apps (that you don't publish, etc) option 1 is the choice to go. Either way option 1 would be a more sustainable system

Comment: It just came to me another way. since a contentProvider is just an abstraction and it does not care what the datasource is, instead of using sql as the source i could use firebase db.  Then since the firebase db is wrapped inside a contentProvider i could then expose a URI for other apps to use and make the contentProvider public. I'll have to look more into this but should be possible since contentProvider is a wrapper for multiple data sources either network, local sql. you can make the query command return anything i think.